# Can't get jQuery and IE to be friends

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-cycle

Using jQuery and the Cycle plugin. Runs flawless in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and the latest version of Opera. Won't run in older versions of Opera, and of course, IE. I know its running Java, because its picking up the rollovers.

This is driving me batty. Hopefully its something simple. Here's the code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");

 $("div#slides").cycle({
  fx: 'scrollHorz',
  speed:  'slow', 
  timeout: 0,
  prev: '#prev',
  next: '#next'
 });
```

Really appreciate the help guys.

Comment: Well, jQuery isn't exactly known for being compatible with last-years browsers..

Comment: @Sean - At what point in the question or comments did the OP say IE6?  You shouldn't re-tag unless it's clarifying or fixing the tags...and not based on assumptions.

Comment: @Nick, it was based on 'older (...), IE', but I see how this might not be correct. Will update again. Time to get some sleep I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do, are you sure that

```
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

is what you want to use?  If you want something to be hidden, do this:

```
$("#slideshow").css("display", "none");
```

or better yet:

```
 $("#slideshow").hide();
```

Also, any ID's you have should be unique.  So you shouldn't really have much of a need for a selector like `div#slides`.  If you have multiple elements with the ID of `slides`, you have invalid HTML and are going to probably run into bigger problems...

Comment: "overflow: hidden" makes perfect sense.

Comment: The `overflow` and `display` css properties are **completely** different, I would delete or update this, as it'll probably get downvoted...

Comment: Thanks Dave! Problem was me accidentally putting slideshow instead of slides. Works now in both IE and Opera.

Removed overflow:hidden as well.